# Exposing a type-safe dynamic API with a shared library

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, shared-libraries

I'm programming a plugin API interface for an application. The plugins are loaded as shared libraries at run time. They have access to the application API through an interface, such as the following:

```
class IPluginAPI
{
public:
 virtual bool IsPluginsLoaded(void) = 0;
 virtual bool IsHookingEnabled(void) = 0;
 // And about 50 more methods
};
```

Plugins can request to 'listen' on certain events (such as `MouseClick`, `MouseScroll` etc.). These functions make up a total of >300 different events. Normally I would have done something like this:

```
extern "C" void SetEventHooks(APITable& table)
{
 table.MouseClick = &PluginMouseClickEvent;
 table.MouseMove = &PluginMouseMoveEvent;
}
```

Whereas the `SetEventHooks`function resides within the plugin library and is called from the application, and the plugins can listen to functions of interest by pointing to their functions. This is not the method I want to use, but I want to offer some kind of abstraction instead. This is what I had in mind:

```
// Interface IPluginAPI supplies a 'SetEventHook` method such as
void SetEventHook(HookID id, void * callback);
```

In this case `HookID` is a strong typed enum which contains all function IDs:

```
enum class HookID
{
 MouseClick,
 MouseMove,
 // ...
};
```

So the plugin would use this function to listen to events:

```
pluginAPI->SetEventHook(ID::MouseClick, &myCallback);
```

The problem with this approach is that it is not type-safe and I cannot use templates directly (since this is done at runtime as libraries). I don't want to expose 300 different functions either for each event (e.g`SetHookMouseMove(void (*)(int, int))` and so on). My last idea, is that the plugins have a utility template function which makes this type safe, but I'm not sure how to implement this in a simple way (and without boilerplate code):

```
template <typename T>
SetEventHook(HookID id, T callback)
{
 if(typeof(T) == decltype(/* function type of the ID */))
  gPluginAPI->SetEventHook(id, callback);
 else static_assert("INVALID FUNCTION TYPE");
}
```

So to put it simple; how can I enable my plugins to hook to certain events in a dynamic type-safe way without exposing a complete function table and/or >300 methods for each event?

NOTE: I used function pointers for simplification, but I want to use `std::function`

Comment: Is polymorphism not an option? It seems to me that if you have a base class for arguments and for return values of which there are subclasses for each event, a little use of `dynamic_cast`, and everything is good.

Comment: Nah, that's just gonna make things worse. Exponential argument combinations.

Comment: What exactly is `T` supposed to be? You know that function pointers and object pointers are not in general compatible?

Comment: @KerrekSB Of course. As mentioned I used function pointers for simplification, but T would in reality be a std::function.

Comment: Hm, maybe something like `template <HookID ID> void SetEventHook(typename CallbackType<ID>::type callback);`?

Comment: That might just do it! It would be clean and sleek! Only downside is the requirement of a global API object. Could you write that more explanatory and as an answer perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Kerrek, you can use traits policy to solve your problem. Basically as a part of public API you have to include structures defining callback type for each of your hook id.

```
// The default traits. If you don't want to have default traits comment body
// of this type out (including curly braces).
template <HookID id>
struct CallbackTraits
{
   typedef void (*CallbackType)();
};

// Traits for MouseClick
template <>
struct CallbackTraits<HookID::MouseClick>
{
    typedef void (*CallbackType)(int);
};

// Traits for MouseDoubleClick are the same
template <>
struct CallbackTraits<HookID::MouseDoubleClick> : CallbackTraits<HookID::MouseClick> {};

// Traits for MouseMove
template <>
struct CallbackTraits<HookID::MouseMove> 
{
    typedef void (*CallbackType)(int, int);
};


// actual hooking function
template <HookID id>
void SetEventHook(typename CallbackTraits<id>::CallbackType callback)
{
    // do something with id and the callback
}
```

Now you can use this API following way:

```
// handlers prototypes
void MouseClicked(int button);
void MouseMoved(int x, int y);
void SomeEvent();

int main()
{
    // compiles ok
    SetEventHook<HookID::MouseClick>(MouseClicked);
    SetEventHook<HookID::MouseMove>(MouseMoved);

    // won't compile - function signature incompatible
    SetEventHook<HookID::MouseDoubleClick>(MouseMoved);

    // will compile if you left default traits body uncommented
    SetEventHook<HookID::HookWithNoTraitsDefined>(SomeEvent);
    return 0;
}
```

I've uploaded a working sample [here](http://ideone.com/clone/CgRzy).

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, so I'll accept this as my answer!